# How to access Azure resources through powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Just want to know how can I get the service buses in the portal through powershell

I was able to access the app insights through this piece of script

```
az monitor  app-insights component show | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now I wish to access the service bus , app service and app service plans as well through powershell

I was using this

```
az monitor  servicebus component show | ConvertFrom-Json
```

for service bus but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Azure CLI there, not the PowerShell modules.
If you want to list / show the details around the following services, then you need to use the corresponding Azure CLI commands:

1. *ServiceBus*

   `az servicebus namespace show --resource-group myresourcegroup --name mynamespace`

   Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/namespace?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-namespace-show
2. *App Service*

   `az webapp show --name MyWebapp --resource-group MyResourceGroup`

   Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-show
3. *App Service Plans*

   `az appservice plan show --name MyAppServicePlan --resource-group MyResourceGroup`

   Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-show

Here is the full CLI reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

To get service bus namespace list in your current subscription, you use below command:

```
az servicebus namespace list
```

[image]

To get the service bus queue list you below command:

```
az servicebus queue list --resource-group myresourcegroup --namespace-name mynamespace
```

If you want for topic, keep topic in place of queue in above command.

If you want to get app service plans use the below command:

```
az appservice plan list
```

Alternatively, you can use azure resource graph query like below for servicebus:

```
resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.servicebus/namespaces'
```

[image]

You can use azure resource graph query like below to get app services:

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.web/sites'
```

[image]

**References taken from:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-list
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus?view=azure-cli-latest

**Edit:**

Yes if you want apim use below query:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.apimanagement/service"
```

[image]

**Get apim Using cli :**

```
 az account set -s "Subscription name"
    $Resources = az resource list   
    $Resources | Where type -in "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service"
```

Comment: and how about the APIM ?

Comment: I have edited my answer including apim.

Comment: How to access apim based on subscription , I do not want to give the rg name and the service name , just want to provide the subscription and get the apim from that particular subscription

Comment: I have edited my answer including apim without using rg name