# How to list down azure resources inside a particular subscription through powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

How to list down all the azure resources viz App services , App service plans , apim , service bus ,cosmos through powershell based on the subscription

The agenda here is to fetch these resources by passing the subscription as a parameter and getting all the respective  resources inside that particular subscription.

I know how to fetch the resources  using the resource group name as the parameter ,for eg

```
az appservice plan list [--resource-group]
```

But here I do not want to fetch based on the resource group , I need to pass the subscription so that all the resources inside that subscription get listed

Answer (score 1):

Using the cli

```
az account set -s production
$Resources = az resource list | ConvertFrom-Json

$FilterType = @('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', 'Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts')
$Resources | Where Type -in $FilterType
```

Using the **Az** module

```
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription 'Production'
$Resources = Get-azresource

$FilterType = @('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', 'Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts')
$Resources | Where ResourceType -in $FilterType
```

AS for viewing just the types so you can make your selection, you can look in the portal URL of the resource or get all types present in your subscription using

```
# Query all resource first...

# Az cli
$Resources | Select -ExpandProperty Type -Unique | Sort-Object

# Az module
$Resources | Select -ExpandProperty ResourceType -Unique | Sort-Object
```

Comment: Thanx for answering and how about specific resources?...Suppose I need only App services or asp or cosmos or service bus?

Comment: @AaryanKhanna Sure, I'd proceed the same way, by first getting all the resouce then filtering down to only the desired type. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> list down azure resources inside a particular subscription through powershell

**In PowerShell using PowerShell Commands:**

Firstly, you need to set azure subscription using below PowerShell command:

xxx = Can be subcription name or id

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxx"
```

Output:

[image]

Then use  below PowerShell command to get all resources in the current Subdcription:

```
Get-AzResource | ft
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

ft means format table

Comment: Thanx for answering and how about specific resources?...Suppose I need only App services or asp or cosmos or service bus?

Comment: please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73795230/how-to-access-azure-resources-through-powershell/73795393#73795393) thread

Comment: yep I have referred that but there apim is taking resource group as the parameter , I do not want to do that , I want to list these resources based on subscription

Comment: By using above command get the details of all resources, from there pick rg name and then send it. AFAIK, this is way to do it. So, these specific commands need to be given in specific format.